# Add a delay in git post-merge

Tags: scripting, git, delay

My scenario is as follows: After updating files on my Git repository, I have a Git hook that calls an API from my web server. This API performs a Git pull and then I have a Git hook post-merge that restart the web server (Gunicorn). The restart of the web server should occurs a few seconds after the pull is completed otherwise the web server is shutting down before the API call is completed and that returns an error to the Git hook.
Currently I worked out the following solution but I am not happy with it.
The file `.git/hooks/post-merge`

```
#!/bin/sh
/var/www/tempcollect/.git/hooks/restart > /var/www/tempcollect/.git/hooks/restart.log &
```

The file `.git/hooks/restart`

```
sleep 10s
/usr/bin/sudo systemctl restart tempcollect
```

I would prefer to have the command to restart the web server in the `post-merge` file.
The execution of the file `post-merge` is started by Git at the end of the pull, thus I have no control on the way it is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended up with this one line in the file `.git/hooks/post-merge`

```
#!/bin/sh
( sleep 10 ; /usr/bin/sudo systemctl restart tempcollect  ) &
```